# How to create a splash screen with a progressbar that will load from 0 to 100% depending on the amount of items loading to listview?

Tags: c#, winforms

In form1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using static System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleElement;

namespace Process_List_App
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private DoubleBufferedListView customListView;
        private Dictionary<int, ListViewItem> processDictionary = new Dictionary<int, ListViewItem>();
        private int spacing = 5; // Adjust spacing as needed

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
           
                // Load the main form content when the splash screen is closed
                InitializeMainForm();           
        }

        private void InitializeMainForm()
        {
            // Create the main form components
            customListView = new DoubleBufferedListView();
            InitializeListView(customListView);
            StartProcessListUpdater();
        }

        private void InitializeListView(DoubleBufferedListView listView)
        {
            // Set ListView properties
            listView.View = View.Details;
            listView.FullRowSelect = true;
            listView.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

            // Create column headers with auto sizing
            listView.Columns.Add("Process Name", -2); // -2 for auto sizing based on content
            listView.Columns.Add("Status", -2); // -2 for auto sizing
            listView.Columns.Add("Date/Time", -2);
            listView.Columns.Add("PID", -2);
            
            // Increase font size for all items
            listView.Font = new Font(listView.Font.FontFamily, 12); // Adjust the font size as needed

            // Set ListView background color for even and odd rows
            listView.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke; // Adjust the background color as needed

            // Add the DoubleBufferedListView control to the form's controls
            Controls.Add(listView);
        }

        private void StartProcessListUpdater()
        {
            // Start the Timer to update the process list
            timer1.Start();
        }

        private void UpdateProcessList()
        {
            // Suspend the layout to prevent flickering
            customListView.BeginUpdate();

            // Get the list of running processes
            Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();

            foreach (Process process in processes)
            {
                // Check if the process is already in the dictionary
                if (processDictionary.ContainsKey(process.Id))
                {
                    // Update the process status and timestamp
                    ListViewItem item = processDictionary[process.Id];
                    item.SubItems[2].Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                }
                else
                {
                    // Create a new ListViewItem for the process
                    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(process.ProcessName);
                    item.SubItems.Add("Opened"); // Set the status as "Opened" for new processes
                    item.SubItems.Add(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")); // Add the timestamp
                    item.SubItems.Add(process.Id.ToString());

                    // Add the new item to the customListView
                    customListView.Items.Add(item);
                    // Add the item to the dictionary for future reference
                    processDictionary.Add(process.Id, item);
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < customListView.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i % 2 == 0)
                    customListView.Items[i].BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
                else
                    customListView.Items[i].BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
            }

            customListView.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize);

            // Check for killed processes
            foreach (int processId in processDictionary.Keys.ToList())
            {
                if (processes.All(p => p.Id != processId))
                {
                    // Process no longer exists, mark as killed and update the timestamp
                    ListViewItem item = processDictionary[processId];
                    item.SubItems[1].Text = "Killed";
                    item.SubItems[2].Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                    item.BackColor = Color.Red; // Color for killed processes
                }
            }

            // Resume the layout after updates
            customListView.EndUpdate();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Update the process list on each Timer tick
            UpdateProcessList();
        }
    }
}
```

The I created a usercontrol  with a progressBr in the designer:

[image: usercontrol]

The code in the usercontrol:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Process_List_App
{
    public partial class SplashScreenControl : UserControl
    {
        public SplashScreenControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public ProgressBar Progress()
        {
            return progressBar1;
        }
    }
}
```

Then created a new form and using in the form with the usercontrol.
I ragged to the new form designer the created usercontrol with the rogressBar:

[image: new form with the usercontrol]

and the code in the new form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Process_List_App
{
    public partial class SplashScreenForm : Form
    {
        public ProgressBar ProgressBar => splashScreenControl1.Progress();

        public SplashScreenForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void SplashScreenForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var timer = new Timer();
            timer.Interval = 100; // Adjust this interval as needed.
            timer.Tick += async (s, args) =>
            {
                if (ProgressBar.Value < ProgressBar.Maximum)
                {
                    ProgressBar.Value++;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Loading is complete; close the splash screen.
                    timer.Stop();
                    await Task.Delay(500); // Add a slight delay before closing.
                    Close();
                }
            };
            timer.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

What have I tried so far:
I tried to use the splash screen in the form1 constructor this way:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Initialize the main form components first
    InitializeComponent();

    // Create the splash screen form
    var splashScreenForm = new SplashScreenForm();

    // Subscribe to the splash screen's Closed event
    splashScreenForm.FormClosed += (sender, e) =>
    {
        // Load the main form content when the splash screen is closed
        InitializeMainForm();
    };

    // Show the splash screen
    splashScreenForm.Show();
}
```

but what it does is putting the splash screen form behind the form1 and the progressBar is getting from 0 to 100% but too slow and without any sync to the loading items to the listview.

if not using the splash screen the items are loading to the listview much faster taking about 2-3 seconds with the splash screen it's taking to get to 100% about 10 seconds.

I want the splash screen progressBar to get from 0 to 100% depending on the number of items and the time it's taking to add the items to the listView.

Comment: You are doing everything on the UI thread, meaning the progress cannot update while you are listing the processes. You need to generate ListViewItems in a background task, and add the items to the listView on the UI thread when the task is done.